# How to configure Apache 2.2 for django 1.1 on Windows xp

Tags: django, apache, webserver

I been having hard times configuring Apache 2.2 for Django app that will run on a local area network. I been through a lot of tutorials and documentations still can not get it working for me

My question is there a straight , step by step method for configuring Apache 2.2 for windows

i ready to try anything that will work

thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Bitnami Django stack](http://bitnami.org/stack/djangostack)

> It includes ready-to-run versions of
>   Apache, MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite and
>   Django and required dependenciesDjango and required dependencies